# Is it possible to add a separator to vertical paging in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UITextView, which is obviously inheriting from UIScrollView and I'm using the paging enabled set to yes.

The paging is working but is hard to really see pages, is it possible to easily add a separator between one page and the other?

I've tried

```
textView.contentInset and textView.textContainerInset
```

but those add just insets to the whole textView.